# Cannot see "Waiting for connection from remote gdb..."

Tags: linux, debugging, kernel, kgdb

I'm now configuring kgdb with a target pc and a host pc.
These 2 PCs are connected via serial cable.
The host PC has USB-to-Serial cable which is ttyUSB0.
And the target PC has conventional serial port which is ttyS0.

The target PC's BIOS has serial console redirection option so I turned it off.

The Kernel of target PC is built with the following options.

1) CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KGDB = y

2) CONFIG_KGDB = y

3) CONFIG_KGDB_SERIAL_CONSOLE = y

And the following is the line of grub.cfg

linux /vmlinuz ro PROMPT_NO nmi_watchdog=1 kgdbwait kgdb8250=/dev/ttyS0,9600,kgdboc=/dev/ttyS0,9600 quiet

I have grub2 installed in this target PC.

I was expecting "Waiting for connection from remote gdb..." message.
But it does boot normally without any message.

After booting I checked the /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc and it was empty.

Comment: Parameters to Linux kernel should be delimited with space (` `), not by comma (`,`).

Comment: Is it only for grub2 or legacy grub as well?

Comment: I tried without comma in front of kgdboc. "linux /vmlinuz ro PROMPT_NO nmi_watchdog=1 kgdbwait kgdb8250=/dev/ttyS0,9600 kgdboc=/dev/ttyS0,9600 quiet" But the result is still same.